# Block list of Phone numbers using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry

I have researched a lot but i didnt find anything on Google to Block phone numbers using **phonegap**.

Is it possible to block these numbers or show as Busy if a particular number is called, any code please

Comment: What OS are you talking about? Android/OS/Blackberry? You'll need to use some native code, so it will be different per platform, if it is even possible on each one.

Comment: @RichBradshaw Android, Blackberry